# imagecreatefromjpeg not giving me a resource?

Tags: php

I am trying to code a script for file resizing.In the script, I use getimagesize() to get the mime information from the image and then test it's value using a switch statement, assigning different values to variables in different cases.

However after running the script, I'm getting the error

```
PHP Warning:  imagecopyresampled() expects parameter 2 to be resource, string given in ..........
```

Why exactly am I getting this error when all I'm doing is passing it the variable from createimagefromjpeg?

My Code extract:

```
list($width,$height,$type)=getimagesize($_FILES["BusinessCreateFileUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
        //checks the mime type and gets the extension
        //Declares the $uploadedfile,$src and $ext variables.
        $uploadedfile='';
        $src='';
        $ext='';
        switch($type)
        {
            case"image/jpeg":
                $uploadedfile=$_FILES["BusinessCreateFileUpload"]["tmp_name"];
                $src=imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedfile);
                $ext=".jpg";
                break;
            case"image/png":
                $uploadedfile=$_FILES["BusinessCreateFileUpload"]["tmp_name"];
                $src=imagecreatefrompng($uploadedfile);
                $ext=".png";
                break;
            default:
                echo"An error has occurred.Please follow the <a href='http://localhost/Kenced/Business/edititem.php'>link to try again</a>";
        }
        //Creates thumbnail
        $newwidth=100;
        $newheight=100;
        $thumbimg=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
        imagecopyresampled($thumbimg,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth,$newheight,$width,$height);
        //Creates displayimage
        $newwidth1=250;
        $newheight1=250;
        $displayimg=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth1, $newheight1);
        imagecopyresampled($displayimg,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth1,$newheight1,$width,$height);
```

I'm editing bits and pieces of a script I found on the internet as I'm still rather new to programming so I might have inadvertently screwed something up, though I can't seem to figure out where exactly did I go wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code sets a default value of `$src` to an empty string. The following lines are then accessing this empty string of `$src`, which is why it is giving the error:

```
imagecopyresampled($thumbimg,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth,$newheight,$width,$height);
imagecopyresampled($displayimg,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth1,$newheight1,$width,$height);
```

As per your code, this would occur when the `switch` case for `$type` is assuming a default value, and therefore your code must be outputting the following line as well:

> An error has occurred.Please follow the [link to try again](http://domainname.com/Kenced/Business/edititem.php)

---

Regarding OP's comment (the answer seemed long, so including it here):

- First, make your script use `die` instead of `echo` in your `default case` of the switch statement. So, if the value of `$type` is not as desired, then the script will give an error and stop.
- Secondly, the function `getimagesize` returns mimetype as an INT value, which is what your variable `$type` will be set as. Instead, you are comparing your `$type` variable to strings which is wrong, and would always make use of the `default` case. Therefore, change your `switch` statement and compare the values to INT values.
- Also, make sure your `case` statements and `echo` statements have a space after keywords, i.e. after `case` and `echo`

---

Considering the above, you can replace your switch statement with this:

```
$src = 0;
switch($type)
    {
        case 2:
            $uploadedfile=$_FILES["BusinessCreateFileUpload"]["tmp_name"];
            $src=imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedfile);
            $ext=".jpg";
            break;
        case 3:
            $uploadedfile=$_FILES["BusinessCreateFileUpload"]["tmp_name"];
            $src=imagecreatefrompng($uploadedfile);
            $ext=".png";
            break;
        default:
            die "An error has occurred.Please follow the <a href='http://localhost/Kenced/Business/edititem.php'>link to try again</a>";
    }
```

Comment: Why isn't it accessing the value i assigned to $src in the Switch statement? Also how would i solve this problem, since i believe that i cant declare variables in a switch statement?

Answer (score 0):

The `getimagesize` function returns in 3th parameter the type using a int value, not a string mimetype.

Check the docs in [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php).

> 1 = GIF, 2 = JPG, 3 = PNG, 4 = SWF, 5 = PSD, 6 = BMP, 7 = TIFF(intel
> byte order), 8 = TIFF(motorola byte order), 9 = JPC, 10 = JP2, 11 =
> JPX, 12 = JB2, 13 = SWC, 14 = IFF, 15 = WBMP, 16 = XBM

`var_dump` the `$type` variable.

Comment: Also, I recommend you stop the script in case of `default`.